# docker microservice err_connection_refused

Tags: java, docker, microservices

I'm trying to test a microservice running from docker.

Without docker I can access it on `http://localhost:9999/`

When I build the image, run it and try the same address `http://localhost:9999/` I get `err_connection_refused`

In my dockerfile I

```
EXPOSE 9999
```

And when running the image I map ports

```
docker run -i -t 6bcb62617b00 -p 9999:9999
```

But this dosn't help.

```
`Docker-machine` ls returns `tcp://192.168.99.100:2376`
```

I am using docker quickstart terminal for testing.
This is the message I get when running the image `Tomcat started on port(s): 9999`

docker ps 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it had something to do with the way I run it.
Here

```
docker run -d --network=name -p 9999:9999 beeline/dim_source_taxon
```

Instead of image id I use repository to start microservice and when I try

```
docker ps
```

I get
[image]

Also, instead of `localhost` I have to use the host provided by comand `docker-machine ls`